finite diffrence scheme in two dimension
for u solution of :
$$
 \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}+u(1-u), \quad t>0, \quad(x, y) \in \Omega$$
$$
u(x, y, 0)=u^0(x, y),  \quad(x, y) \in \Omega_0 \subset \Omega, 
u=0, \quad t>0, \quad(x, y) \in \partial \Omega$$
where $\Omega=\{(x, y):|x|<a,|y|<b\}, \partial \Omega=\{(x, y):|x|=a or |y|=b\}$, , $\Omega_0$ is a local subset of $\Omega$ .
here  the following finite difference sheme(in 2D) :
$\Omega$ is divided into a regular, rectangular grid with node points $\left(x_n, y_m\right)$
$x_n=-a+(n-1) h,  n=1,2, \ldots, N$
$y_m=-b+(m-1) k,  m=1,2, \ldots, M$
where $h=(2 a) /(N-1)$ and $k=(2 b) /(M-1)$
Writing $t_p=p \tau, p=1,2, \ldots$, where $\tau>0$ is the time step, we can then discretize $u(x, y, t)$ into
$u_{n m}^p=u(x_n, y_m, t_p)$
$$u_{n, m}^{p+1}=u_{n, m}^p+\tau{\frac{1}{h^2}[u_{n+1, m}^p-2 u_{n, m}^p+u_{n-1, m}^p]+\frac{1}{k^2}[u_{n, m+1}^p-2 u_{n, m}^p+u_{n, m-1}^p]+ u_{n, m}^p(1-u_{n, m}^p)}$$
$n=2, \ldots, N-1 \quad m=2, \ldots, M-1$
For the boundary condition , we should use
$$u_{1, m}^{p+1}=u_{N, m}^{p+1}=0,  m=1,2, \ldots, M $$
$$u_{n, 1}^{p+1}=u_{n, M}^{p+1}=0,  n=1,2, \ldots, N $$.
$\Omega$ is divided into a regular, rectangular grid with node points $\left(x_n, y_m\right)$
$$x_n=-a+(n-1) h,  n=1,2, \ldots, N$$
$$y_m=-b+(m-1) k,  m=1,2, \ldots, M$$ i know how to do the finite difference scheme with matrix representation but i dont see how to do it in 2D?

you need to label the points in 2D in an order, usually either row major or column major, then you can build the matrix.

You are considering an explicit scheme, why do you feel the need to have a matrix representation? You can just implement your recursive formula exactly as it is.
If you still want a matrix representation, which is important if you want to move to an implicit scheme, you just need to come up with a single numbering of the nodes, for instance left to right and bottom up. You'll get a penta-diagonal matrix.

Technically you don't need a matrix representation for an implicit scheme, as iterative linear solvers only require a function $x\mapsto Ax$, which can be done efficiently with a loop.

@whpowell96 You are correct, thanks for the comment. However, I think that at an introductory level it still makes sense to associate the need for a matrix representation with the implicit methods.

@PierreCarre  thanks i needed this representation to study the solution numerically

@whpowell96  Thanks  for your answer could you explain more? imean when you say"as iterative linear solvers only require a function x↦Ax
, which can be done efficiently with a loop."since its two dimension

If $N$ is the number of nodes along a single side of a square domain, then we have $N^2$ unknowns, so the matrix would have $N^4$ entries. This can be too much for some linear solvers so matrix-free methods (Newton-Krylov) allow you to only work with a function that computes the action of the PDE on a vector, i.e., not use the matrix representation. Looping over every node is about $N^2$ work so this can be faster than working with the matrix in some cases.

@whpowell96 thanks for clarification
